# error after change in authentication in Spotify API

Tags: javascript, php, api, spotify

After Spotify change the form to use the API for a search data, now required an access token. I added a headers with the access token, but i get an error.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&limit=20&query=' + query,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer <?php echo $token; ?>' 
            },
        datatype: 'json'    
        success: formatArtists,
        error: function() {
            console.log('fatal error!!!')
        },
```

To obtained the token, used this code in PHP:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
$method = 'POST';

$credentials = "CLIENT ID'S";

$headers = array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent: runscope/0.1",
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));
$data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($ch);
$token = $response['access_token'];
```

I has probed the access token in the Spotify web console and works, Has anyone managed to fix this error with the Spotify API?

Comment: Does `cross-origin request policy` allow you to ajax other resources?

Comment: Can you log the error itself and paste it here?